# Orgcharts implementation in Symfony Twig error

Tags: orgchart

Please help.I have a problem with implementation of [orgcharts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart#loading") in Symfony 2.8 project. When I put example code to the twig file the result page draws additional lines not associated with the hierarchy.

Print screen below :

[image: Printscreen]

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Example{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/href/css/home.css') }}"/>
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
            data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

            // For each orgchart box, provide the name, manager, and tooltip to show.
            data.addRows([
                [{v:'Mike', f:'Mike<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>'},
                    '', 'The President'],
                [{v:'Jim', f:'Jim<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vice President</div>'},
                    'Mike', 'VP'],
                ['Alice', 'Mike', ''],
                ['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge'],
                ['Carol', 'Bob', ''],
                ['Carol', 'Bob', '']
            ]);

            // Create the chart.
            var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
            chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
        }
    </script>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Do anyone implemented orgcharts in twig before? Please help.

Comment: As you are using the demo code the problem will be located in your CSS file and has nothing to do with twig

Comment: @DarkBee you are absolutely right. Thanks. Bbootstrap css cause the problem. Now I wonder if I must reformat my site on front ...